# How do I proper handle mobile cross-platform and multi-logins in-app purchases server synchronization?

Tags: android, ios, authentication, notifications, in-app-purchase

**Please consider this context:**

- App X runs on iOS and Android;
- App X offers a subscription for product A and a subscription for product B;
- App X offers an email-based login to identify the user over multiple iOS and Android devices.

**Use case:**

1. John logs in on App X on his device;
2. John subscribes to product A;
3. App X sends the app receipt of the device to the server;
4. The server verifies the receipt and registers the transaction contained in the receipt associating them with the user login;
5. John is with a friend and his device is dead. John asks Tim to use their device;
6. Tim is subscribed to product B of App X;
7. John logs in with his account on Tim's device;
8. App X sends the receipt of App X on Tim's device to the server;
9. The server verifies the receipt and registers the transaction contained in the receipt associating them with the user login;

**OBSERVE:**

At this point, the server registered that John has access to product A and product B, although John had only paid for product A.
Note that if Tim logs in on John's device, they would gain access to product A too and B too, although they only paid product B.

**QUESTION:**

How would you solve this problem? Do you see a different solution or something wrong with my walkthrough?

**MORE CASES:**

8. John buy a new product from Tim's device (but it's logged with his own account).

**RESULT:**

The receipt on Tim's app now contains Tim's products and John's products. The server instead, contains a subset of purchases of this receipt for Tim and a subset for John.

**THEN:**

Tim delete the app and reinstall it. Tim taps on restore purchases and the receipt are sent to the server again. Now Tim's gained access to products bought from while John was logged in.

Comment: What's your desired behavior and what have you tried? Where are you having trouble? Different apps handle this different ways so maybe you can add some detail of what you're trying to do. Why don't you just skip step #9 if you already have the receipt associated with Tim?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet. I'm not using a server at the moment.

Do you see any edge case if I skip point 9? You suggest then to not send the receipt anymore if a user has already created a login, and they already sent their receipt once? And what happens then if they log in from another device or from the same device, buy something, but the AppStore account of that device is different? The receipt would be different. They paid for 2 products with 2 different AppStore accounts, but the same login.

Comment: On step 4, you should associate the subscription to John (and not to John's device). On step 7, when John logs in with Tim's device, your server will already know that John's subscription is A, and everything will work just fine (you won't need 8 or 9).
If you always make your app retrieve info from your server, you'll also have the John's subscription working on both of his device (iOS and android), without any more receipt validation.

Comment: Thanks - Step 4: is what I wrote "user login" not user's device. Step 7: it doesn't cover all cases. For example. I delete the app. I reinstall the app, create a new login user on my device and tap restore purchase. That device has a subscription in the receipt, but following what you wrote, this receipt won't be sent to the server for this new user. Basically what you said works (and I thought to that of course) but doesn't cover all edge cases. There are at least 3 or 4 use cases that break this approach.